# Convert LSTM-LSTM model to CNN-LSTM model

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, conv-neural-network, lstm

```
from keras import  regularizers,constraints,initializers
model = Sequential() 

FIRST_LSTM = 256
SECOND_LSTM = 256
EMBEDD_VECTOR_LENGTH = 128
outputs=[]
inputs_=[]
EMB = Embedding(DICTIONARY_LENGTH, EMBEDD_VECTOR_LENGTH, input_length=30)
BDR = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(FIRST_LSTM,return_sequences=True),merge_mode='concat')
TDB = TimeDistributed(Dense(DICTIONARY_LENGTH+3))
for i in range(SENTENCES_IN_NOVEL): # SENTENCES_IN_NOVEL = 100
    if(i%10==0):
      print(i,"/",SENTENCES_IN_NOVEL)
    inputlayer = Input(shape=[MAX_LENGTH]) # MAX_LENGTH = 30 (30 words per sentence)
    inputs_.append(inputlayer)
    layer = EMB(inputlayer) # 50 is embedd vector size for each POS Tag
    layer =  BDR(layer) # output 100 because of bidirectonal concat
    layer =  Lambda( lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1), input_shape=(30,2*FIRST_LSTM))(layer)
    outputs.append(layer)

merge_ = concatenate(outputs)
merge_ = Reshape((SENTENCES_IN_NOVEL, 2*FIRST_LSTM), input_shape=(SENTENCES_IN_NOVEL*(2*FIRST_LSTM),))(merge_)
merge_ = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(SECOND_LSTM,return_sequences=True),merge_mode='concat')(merge_)

attention_mul = Attention(100)(merge_)#step_dimen =100
output = Dense(14, activation='softmax')(attention_mul)

model = Model(inputs=inputs_,outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

I wrote this model to predict author of Novels LSTM-LSTM Model.
Wants to convert CNN-LSTM.

I am unable to figure out this problem.

Comment: What is exactly your goal? Replace the first LSTM with a 1D CNN?

Comment: Yes! My goal is to convert first LSTM to CNN I have 3D input and wants to output 1D to send in next LSTM. @Jindřich

Comment: Replace `BDR` by  `1D CNN` and add a `max pool layer` after that.